# Choosing exactly 3 boys and 2 girls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

*There are 5 seats vacant in a college, so more candidates are called. Suppose, the next 5 on the waiting list have an equal probability of being a boy or a girl. What is the probability that exactly 3 girls and 2 boys are admitted?*

In this question the answer is given as $5/16$.
The process:
$${5 \choose 3} \times \frac{1}{32}$$

But I think that there is no need for picking seats particularly.

Could anyone point out the mistake I am making in this?

**Why is $5 \choose 3$ multiplied?**

Comment: Where do you think the 1/32 comes from?

Comment: (1/2)³×(1/2)² ,probability of  the student being a boy=probability being a girl=1/2 , so for 3 boys and 2 girls it's 1/32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$^5C_3$ is not referencing the seats at all. You have a fixed number of seats and an equal number of people waiting.

To have a better understanding, ignore the part about vacant seats completely (since an equal number of candidates are available). Your problem is now equivalent to you having $5$ students and the probability that $3$ of them are girls and $2$ are boys.

How do you find this? *Break down your desired situation into parts that must happen together*.

1. you choose $3$ out of $5$ students that are necessarily girls
2. the rest are necessarily boys

Situation $1$ happens with probability $^5C_3\times P($those $3$ are girls$)$. Similarly for situation $2$. Why do we multiply? Because they must happen together (you add when it is an **OR** situation and multiply when it is **AND**).

Answer (score 2):

Unordered probabilities are often difficult. Ordered probabilities are often easier. In order to reason about the unordered 5 vacant spots and how to fill them, it is in my opinion easier to pretend they are ordered, and argue from there.

Thus we list all the possible ways to get two girls and three boys.

- The probability that we get GGBBB, that is to say, the first two seats filled with girls, and the last three seats filled with boys is $\frac1{32}$.
- The probability that we get GBGBB is $\frac1{32}$
- The probability that we get GBBGB is $\frac1{32}$
- The probability that we get GBBBG is $\frac1{32}$

and so on. These events are all disjoint, so the probability that one of them happens is the sum of all the probabilities for each one. These events also happen to all be equally likely, so instead of adding them all together, we just multiply this probability of $\frac1{32}$ with how many of these events there are. How many are there? Exactly $^5C_3 = \binom 53$. This gives the final result you were given.